# My pointer is not returning NULL but the file it is paining at does not exist

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to write to files using fopen, with a NULL check in case there is an error opening the file or it does not exist. However despite the file not existing the pointer returns with an arbitrary number instead of being NULL. Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

My code is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int writenumstofile(int num1, int num2) 
{
    FILE* fp;

    if ((fp = fopen("outpiuteuo.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        return 7;
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%d", num1);
    fprintf(fp, "%d", num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "w

Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file."

Comment: @Stargateur, Thanks I don't need to write to the file if it doesn't exist I only need the pointer to return as null, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I believe "r+" will do it, read [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) when you want use a function.

Comment: thanks that solved the problem

Comment: If you just change it to NULL then you will lose a pointer, so you won't be able to close the file later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is creating a file if it doesn't exist. If you don't want the file to be created then use `r+` file or simply first open the file in `r` mode and the proceed with `w` mode.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it doing this and simply flag it as null?

Comment: @user10486019 Updated my answer.